# Check if object is empty in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: javascript, github, javascript-objects, github-actions

I'm running a test using a GitHub Actions workflow, and I would like to fail the test if the resulting object produced by the test is empty. How do I check if a JSON object is empty?

My current workflow job contains the step:

```
- name: Fail if security tests found any issues
  if: ${{ steps.securityTestsResults != {} }}
  uses: actions/github-script@v3
  with:
    script: |
        core.setFailed('security tests failed: non-empty results')
```

But the code above currently results in the error:

```
Invalid workflow file : .github/workflows/securityTests.yml#L34
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/securityTests.yml (Line: 34, Col: 11): Unexpected symbol: '{}'. Located at position 31 within expression: steps.securityTestsResults != {}
```

It's confusing since I believe my code would work in regular javascript, but it doesn't appear to work here. I've also tried `Object.keys(obj).length === 0` and `JSON.stringify(obj) == '{}'` but these don't work either (it doesn't recognize the `Object` or `JSON` classes).

Comment: What is Line: 34, Col: 11?

Comment: It's the line containing the `if: ${{ steps.securityTestsResults != {} }}`

Comment: Looks like a yaml escaping issue. Have you tried putting the line within double quotes?

Comment: Ok, I tried changing it to `if: "${{ steps.securityTestsResults != {} }}"` but I still got exactly the same error.

Comment: Sorry that may make it a string which is not what you want. Another thing you could try is to use the pipe | and add the code on the next line just like you did in your script key

Comment: Sorry I got the same error again. I'm thinking that `if` conditions in workflows might be more limited than normal javascript. I don't know how to work around it though--this seems like it should be so simple!

Comment: Write a local js GitHub action. It’s simple enough and you can run real js

Comment: What is the type of `steps.securityTestResults`? String?

Comment: @soltex It's an Object. It's produced as the JSON output of the mobsfscan GitHub Actions workflow.

Comment: Your `steps.securityTestResults` seems weird, it should be something like `steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_id>`. Anyway, you can create another step (eg: `validate_object`, it should return true or false) using `actions/github-script@v3` and use javascript to validate the object, and then use it in your next step as `if ${{ steps.<step_id>.outputs.result }}`.

Comment: Ok, so like Dominik was saying, it seems like I have to create my own GitHub action to evaluate the object using javascript, or use an inline-javascript GitHub action like this one: https://github.com/actions/github-script ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `toJSON`:

```yaml
if: toJSON(steps.securityTestsResults) == "{}"
```

(You don't need the wrapping `${{ }}` in an `if` statement, as they're always evaluated as expressions.)

Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson

Comment: This is the right way, but you need single quotes, not double quotes (see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals, otherwise you confuse the parser).

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: Check HOST ENV
   uses: actions/github-script@v4
   with:
    script: |
      if( "${{env.HOST}}" == "ERR" ){
        core.setFailed('Error mnj')
      }
```